# How to read in plist data into a data model?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I started my app by hardcoding some static data (hotel info) inside my data model so that they are accessible everywhere in my app. This was fine until the list started to grow (still static data). I'm trying to figure out how to recreate the hardcoded data by using a plist instead. Seems straight forward but can't seem to figure it out.

My "hotel" object header:

```
@interface Hotel : NSObject {}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int HotelID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* Name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) int Capacity;

@end
```

My "hotel" object implementation:

```
@implementation Hotel

@synthesize HotelID, Name, Capacity;

-(void)dealloc {
    [Name release];
    [Capacity release];
}
```

The "Hotel" object is managed by my DataModel.
The header for DataModel:

```
@class Hotel;

@interface DataModel : NSObject {}

-(int)hotelCount;
```

The DataModel implementation:

```
#import "DataModel.h"
#import "Hotel.h"

// Private methods
@interface DataModel ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *hotels;

-(void)loadHotels;

@end

@implementation DataModel

@synthesize hotels;

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        [self loadHotels];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [hotels release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)loadHotels

hotels = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:30] retain];

Hotel *hotel = [[Hotel alloc] init];
hotel.HotelID = 0;
hotel.Name = @"Solmar";
hotel.Capacity = 186;
// more data to be added eventually
[hotels addObject:hotel];
[hotel release];

Hotel *hotel = [[Hotel alloc] init];
hotel.HotelID = 1;
hotel.Name = @"Belair";
hotel.Capacity = 389;
[hotels addObject:hotel];
[hotel release];

// and so on... I have 30 hotels hard coded here.

- (int)hotelCount {
    return self.hotels.count;
}

@end
```

This setup works fine. However, I can't figure out how to implement the loadHotel section where the data is hard coded. I would like to replace this with a plist with the same information. How do I read in the plist file to assign information for every key (name, capacity, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you create the plist, you can load its contents into a dictionary like this:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:plistFileName ofType:nil];
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Then you can query whatever data you need using the keys from the plist:

```
NSArray *hotelsFromPlist = [plistDict objectForKey:"hotels"];

// remember this is autoreleased, so use alloc/initWithCapacity of you need to keep it
NSMutableArray *hotels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[hotelsFromPlist count]];

for (NSDictionary *hotelDict in hotelsFromPlist) {
    Hotel *hotel = [[Hotel alloc] init];
    hotel.name = [hotelDict objectForKey:@"name"];
    hotel.capacity = [hotelDict objectForKey:@"capacity"];
    [hotels addObject:hotel];
}
```

Hope this helps.

edited for code correctness

Comment: Thanks for your help! The line NSArray *hotelsFromPlist = [NSDictionary objectForKey:"hotels"]; returns an error "Class method '+objectForKey:' not found (return type defaults to 'id'). Do you know why this is?

Comment: A quick question: In your example, *plistDict is an unused variable. Where do I use it?

Comment: Thanks devdavid. I tried implementing this using your code example but I am getting an error (Collection was mutated while being enumerated). My code: `NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]; NSString* plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"HotelList" ofType:@"plist"]; hotels = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacityOfFile:[plistPath] retain]; for (NSDictionary *hotelDict in hotels) { // code as shown in your example }` This code successfully read in each hotel dict but then throws an exception when its done. Can you see why?

Comment: devdavid's answer is correct for me since I won't have to write any data.

Comment: oops, sorry about that.  The line: NSArray *hotelsFromPlist = [NSDictionary objectForKey:"hotels"]; needs to have plistDict instead of NSDictionary.  Also, your for loop needs to loop through "hotelsFromPlist" and not "hotels", since "hotels" is the one you are filling up.  The reason for the exception is that you are changing the "hotels" array in a loop that is iterating over the same array.  Let the loop iterate through the hotelsFromPlist array, and in that fill the hotels array with Hotel objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your object to conforms to NSCoding protocol... That means, you need to implement two methods(don't forget to declare your object as

```
@interface Hotel : NSObject<NSCoding>{
   //your declarations here...
}
```

and the implementation

```
@implementation Hotel
////
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    [aCoder encodeObject:Name forKey:someKeyRepresentingProperty];
    //and so one...
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [self init];
    if(self){
        self.Name = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:someKeyRepresentingProperty];
        //and so one...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then you'll be able to store and read your objects pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm trying it out now but ran into trouble... My Hotel class has an integer called "HotelID". When I tried to encodewithobject and decodewithobjectforkey, I get an error - "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'id'. I should have remembered to put it in my question. (I added it now).

Comment: There are convenience methods for integer storage encodeInt:forKey: and decodeIntForKey: also there's much more methods for other types such float,Integer(int wrapper) and so one...

Comment: I just found that out myself! Should have looked first. I'm going to try it out and see how it goes! I'll post my progress...

Comment: Hmmm... it's not working. I think I'm messing up my loadHotels method. How would I read in the plist? I'm using:

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HotelList" ofType:@"plist"];

hotels = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path] retain];

Seems like I'm missing something...

Comment: I believe you've checked that the file is exists and IS inside the mainBundle!!! Try to initialize it as non mutable array first. Also note, that arrayWith... methods returns you autoreleased object, so you need to retain it if you want it to stay...

Comment: Yes, I checked (and re-checked) that the plist file exists and is in the mainBundle. Thanks for the reminder regarding arrayWith...

Comment: Btw, you need to be exact in order. I'll explain: let's say you've stored an array of your objects, then you need to extract it as array. if you've stored a dictionary - extract dictionary. The structure of the data doesn't change if you've declared you want it in other container...

Comment: Thanks, Ariel. NSCoding protocol seems like the way to go. What do you think about using NSKeyedArchiver?

Comment: I'm using it. Very simple. The same as plist only you can store your data in whatever file you want(regard the filesystem restrictions of course). Works the same way. Actually you can use it if you want to store every object in different file (if I'm right plist is a way to store arrays or dictionaries making some overhead wrapper in case you need every object be separated).

Comment: Another thing about plist files. I've seen in apple examples following usage:    NSArray *__imageData = nil; NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ImageData" ofType:@"plist"]; NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]; NSString *error; NSPropertyListFormat format; __imageData = [[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&error]retain]; It seems that they handle those a little bit differently from any other...