# plist to array "Collection was mutated while being enumerated" exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting exception as “Collection was mutated while being enumerated”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424861/getting-exception-as-collection-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated)

This question is a continuation of another question I posted earlier [How to read in plist data into a data model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422482/how-to-read-in-plist-data-into-a-data-model)
@devdavid's helped me to get this far...

I have a plist file called "HotelList.plist" and it looks like this:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>hotelID</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Solmar</string>
        // ... more keys and strings ...
    </dict>
    // ... more hotel entries ...
</array>
```

I have a "hotel" class describing the keys.
I have a data model class where I would like to read in this plist into an array.

```
#import "DataModel.h"
#import "Hotel.h"

// Private methods
@interface DataModel ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *hotels;

-(void)loadHotels;

@end

@implementation DataModel

@synthesize hotels;

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        [self loadHotels];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [hotels release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)loadHotels {

    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString* plistpath = [bundle pathForResource:@"HotelList" ofType:@"plist"];

    hotels = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistpath]retain];

    for (NSDictionary *hotelDict in hotels) {
        Hotel *hotel = [[Hotel alloc] init];
        hotel.hotelID = [[hotelDict objectForKey:@"hotelID"] intValue];
        hotel.name = [hotelDict objectForKey:@"name"];
        [hotels addObject:hotel];
        [hotel release];
    }
}

@end
```

When I run this, the debugger shows me that each hotel dict was read in but when it reaches the end of the plist (I have about 30 hotels), it tries to go back to the first one and crashes, giving an exception "Collection was mutated while being enumerated".

The green SIGABRT indicator stops on the

```
for (NSDictionary *hotelDict in hotels) {
```

line. Is there something wrong with my for loop? The way I set up the arrays/dictionaries? Or maybe the formatting of the plist is wrong (although I don't think so because the debugger shows me it is reading it correctly)?

For completeness, I should mention that, yes, the plist file is present and is in the mainBundle, and spelled correctly. Also, the data in the plist is static -- I won't have to save anything new to a file.

Please help!

Comment: It sucks, but you have to use a standard `for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++)` loop instead of the `for (NSObject *object in array)` for concurrent modification reasons. I know of only one way to fix this and that is to make a copy of the array beforehand and iterate the copy not the new array which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I did see that post and although it seems related, it did not hep me to solve my problem.

Comment: you're adding the `Hotel` objects to the same array the `NSDictionary` objects are... Is that really what you wanted to do?

Comment: Thanks Richard J. Ross III. Yikes, that sounds painful! Is there a code snippet or something that might make it clearer to me?

Comment: Thanks filipe. Uhm, no, I did't want to do that... Newbie here making dumb mistakes as I learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use accessors, not ivars directly. Your problem would have been more obvious that way, and you'd avoid the possible leak you have in the assignment of `hotel` (if `loadHotels` is every called a second time). Your code reads dictionaries into an array and then tries to append `Hotel` objects onto that same array. Here's what you really meant to say:

```
NSArray *hotelDicts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistpath];
self.hotels = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *hotelDict in hotelDicts) {
    Hotel *hotel = [[Hotel alloc] init];
    hotel.hotelID = [[hotelDict objectForKey:@"hotelID"] intValue];
    hotel.name = [hotelDict objectForKey:@"name"];
    [self.hotels addObject:hotel];
    [hotel release];
}
[hotelDicts release];
```

Comment: Thanks Rob! Worked like a charm. Very educational for me too.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to modify the collection you're enumerating through -- you can't do this.  Instead of using an enumerator, try iterating through the collection instead.  When you iterate through an array, you can still add/remove members of the array because you aren't bound to the enumeration that was defined prior to begining the *for block*.

One way to iterate through the collection is with a simple for loop:

```
for( int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++ )
{
    id object = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    // do something with object
}
```

Comment: Thanks George. Can you explain a little further? I'm not sure if I understand what "iterating through the collection instead" means.